# Pre-Chat: how to block the chat

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat

I have a Liveagent with a Pre-Chat. The Pre-Chat has to be used not properly: if you set SI you have to be redirected to a certain page. If you answer NO the chat session has to be started. I followed the guides but this case is not contemplated. I have used a workaround: beyond the "guide" function handlePageLoad() I inserted the function blockChat() that simply set no actions.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">

<head>

    <!-- This script takes the endpoint URL parameter passed from the deployment 
      page and makes it the action for the form -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

         function handlePageLoad() {
           var endpointMatcher = new RegExp("[\\?\\&]endpoint=([^&#]*)");
           document.getElementById('prechatForm').setAttribute('action',
           decodeURIComponent(endpointMatcher.exec(document.location.search)[1]));
         } 
         if (window.addEventListener) {
                  window.addEventListener('load', handlePageLoad, false);
         } else { 
             window.attachEvent('onload', handlePageLoad, false);
         } 


        function blockTheChat(){    

            if(document.getElementById('customField1').checked)   {
                 document.getElementById('prechatForm').setAttribute('action','');
                window.open('https://andreaianni.branded.me/');
                self.close();
                //liveagent.rejectChat('57324000000TOxS');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Follows the rest of the code:

```
<div id="divElement" align="center">

<h1>Welcome to the page.</h1>
<br/> <br />

  <form method='post' id='prechatForm'> 

  Are you already a client? <br /> <br />

      Si <input type='radio' name='liveagent.prechat:radio'
        id='customField1' /> <!--<br /> -->
      No <input type='radio' name='liveagent.prechat:radio'
        id='customField2' checked="true" /><br /> <br />


      <!-- Map liveagent.prechat:FirstNameDetail and liveagent.prechat:LastNameDetail
        custom detail to Contact's field FirstName and LastName -->
      <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Contact"
        value="FirstName,FirstNameDetail;LastName,LastNameDetail" />

      <!-- Specify to query for a matching Contact records FirstName field based on
        the value of FirstName -->
      <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact"
        value="FirstName,true" />

      <!-- Return results only if there is an exact match of FirstName -->
      <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact"
        value="FirstName,true" />

      <!-- If no match in search, create a new Contact record with the mapped value
        of firstname and last name -->
      <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Contact"
        value="FirstName,true;LastName,true" />

      <!-- If a new Contact record has been created, open it as a subtab -->
      <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Contact"
        value="true" />

      <!-- Save the Contact id to transcript's field ContactId -->
      <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Contact"
        value="ContactId" />

      <input type='submit' value='Request Chat' onclick="openYes()" id='prechat_submit'/> 

  </form> 
</div> 
</apex:page>
```

It works in this case, but since I haven't understood properly what I have done, when I tried to apply that to another problem it doesn't work. So, I need to understand what the handlePageLoad() does in its 3 rows.

> var endpointMatcher = new RegExp("[\?\&]endpoint=([^&#]*)");
>
> document.getElementById('prechatForm').setAttribute('action', decodeURIComponent(endpointMatcher.exec(document.location.search)[1]));